# How would I modify an already drawn Path?

Tags: swiftui

So I have a view of lines. The number of lines are determined by the user's input. I know  about creating lines and how to render those lines with different effects.. but how would I modify a line that has already been created.

So for example I would like to make the second drawn line have a break in the middle after maybe a button tap from the user..

Here is some minimally reproduced code..

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = Path()
    @State private var horizontalLines = 0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                Draw(path: $path)
                    .stroke()
                    .clipped()
                    .padding()
                HorizontalLine(path: $path, horizontalLines: $horizontalLines, rect: geo.frame(in: .local))
            }
        }
    }
    private func addLine() {
        path.addEllipse(in: path.boundingRect)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Draw: Shape {
    @Binding var path: Path
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = path
        path.addRect(rect)
        return path
    }
}

struct HorizontalLine: View {
    @Binding var path: Path
    @Binding var horizontalLines: Int
    let rect: CGRect
    var verticalOffset: CGFloat {
        let height = rect.size.height
        let tenths = height / 10
        return tenths * CGFloat(horizontalLines)
    }
    var body: some View {
        Button("Add Horizontal Lines") {
            path = addHLine()
        }
    }
    private func addHLine() -> Path {
        var path = path
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + 50, y: verticalOffset))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - 75 , y: verticalOffset))
        self.horizontalLines += 1
        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't edit a `Path`/`CGPath`. You will have to copy it and recreate it.

Comment: @George_E Would it be possible then to copy and recreate the Path with a modification to a certain line

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be to call your `addHLine` function with `horizontalLines` reset to `0` before hand in a loop. Check `if horizontalLines == 1` and then draw the line slightly differently, be making two separate lines.